# Spring Boot LDAP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ldap

I am working on Spring Boot application in which I need to verify that is user belong to domain or not? 
To check it I want to verify the username entry though ldap.

Below is code for creating LDAP Configuration:

```java
   @Bean
   public LdapContextSource contextSource(String url, String port, String baseName, String uName, String password) {
          LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
          contextSource.setUrl(url + ":" + port));
          contextSource.setBase(baseName);
          contextSource.setUserDn(uName);
          contextSource.setPassword(password);
          contextSource.setReferral("follow");
          return contextSource;
   }

   @Bean
   public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate(String url, String port, String baseName, String uName, String password) {
       final LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource(url, port, baseName, uName, password));
       return ldapTemplate;
   }
```

I am getting below exception

```
default task-101) Error/Exception occured while login nested exception is javax.naming.PartialResultException [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: DomainDnsZones.magna.global:389; socket closed]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ldapTemplate method add statement `ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);` for ignoring partial result exception.

Answer (score -1):

The connection to LDAP is closed . You need to add the SSL certificate for establishing the connection and check if there are any firewall openings required .